# apply dynamic CSS class from a computed in vue.js on top of other conditional classes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this  `div` in my `Field.vue` component template:

```
<div class="field"
    :class="{
      'has-bomb': field.hasBomb && field.isOpen,
      'is-open': field.isOpen,
      'is-marked': field.isMarked
    }"></div>
```

Now I have a computed that creates a String based on `field.x` and `field.y` like this:

```
computed: {
  cssClass () {
    return `x${this.field.x}-y${this.field.y}`
  }
}
```

How can I add that generated String as a CSS class to my div?

I tried

```
<div class="field"
    :class="{
      'has-bomb': field.hasBomb && field.isOpen,
      'is-open': field.isOpen,
      'is-marked': field.isMarked,
      cssClass
    }"></div>
```

and also

```
<div class="field"
    :class="{
      'has-bomb': field.hasBomb && field.isOpen,
      'is-open': field.isOpen,
      'is-marked': field.isMarked,
      cssClass: true
    }"></div>
```

but that just gives me

```
<div class="field cssClass"></div>
```

instead of what I need, e.g.:

```
<div class="field x3-y10"></div>
```

Comment: try <div class="field"
    :class="{
      'has-bomb': field.hasBomb && field.isOpen,
      'is-open': field.isOpen,
      'is-marked': field.isMarked,
      this.cssClass()
    }"></div>

Comment: There is no `this` in the template in Vue.js.

Comment: what if u drop the 'this' and just do cssClass()?

Comment: `Error compiling template: - invalid expression: Unexpected token } in

    {
    'has-bomb': field.hasBomb && field.isOpen,
    'is-open': field.isOpen,
    'is-marked': field.isMarked,
    cssClass()
  }` changes to  ´Unexpected token :` when I try `cssClass(): true`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this approach, Vue provides so called the [Array Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) class binding, which allow using static or dynamic classes inside an array which is passed to the dynamic html attribute.

**For example**:

```
<div :class="['static-class', computedClass, {'dynamic': obj.enabled}]">Test</div>
```

**REQUIRED IN COMMENTS by @webnoob:** It is also good to know that is possible to use both pure html `class` with vue dynamic `:class` even though in HTML is not valid to use 2 same attributes ([read more in specifications][2]), moreover, nowadays if you try to use multiple same attributes, browsers will just ignore them. But in our case with vue it works because all the dynamic classes will be merged together with the static ones and at the end the element will contain only one class attribute.

**Working example:**

```
<div :class="myClass" class="row">Test</div>
```

But is not possible to use two of the same style (i.e. two dynamic or two static)

**Not working example:**

`<div class="a" class="b"></div>`  or `<div :class="a" :class="b"></div>` 

This generates errors.

Comment: In my case the content of `cssClass` is dynamic, not the condition, like in your example `obj.enabled`.

Comment: you can use static, or dynamic with this syntax... please check I've updated the answer.

Comment: `:class="[
    {
      'has-bomb': field.hasBomb && field.isOpen,
      'is-open': field.isOpen,
      'is-marked': field.isMarked,
    }, cssClass]"` does the job. Thanks for pointing out!